# How to write a Spring Data JPA Specification with multiple joins?

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, jhipster

The project I'm working on was generated with JHipster with support for entity filtering, which uses Spring Data JPA Specifications under the hood.

The model is as follows (in JDL):

```
entity Student {
    name String
}

entity Course {
    name String
}

entity Enrollment {
}

entity Attendance {
    date LocalDate
}

relationship OneToMany {
    Student to Enrollment(student required),
    Course to Enrollment(course required),
    Enrollment to Attendance(enrollment required)
}

filter all
service all with serviceClass
```

JHipster generates boilerplate for filtering `Attendance` by `enrollmentId`, but I'd like to extend it to be able to filter by `studentId` and `courseId` as well.

So, how can I implement a Specification that would perform a query like:

```sql
SELECT
  attendance.date, student.name as student, course.name as course
FROM attendance
JOIN enrollment
  ON enrollment.id = attendance.enrollment_id
JOIN student
  ON student.id = enrollment.student_id
  AND studend.id = 1
JOIN course
  ON course.id = enrollment.course_id
  AND course.id = 2;
```

Comment: There is work being done in jhipster:  https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster/pull/97

Comment: @GaëlMarziou I implemented a simple solution based on the code from your link: `return (root, query, builder) -> builder.equal(root.join(Attendance_.enrollment).join(Enrollment_.student).get(student_.id), studentId);`. Maybe I didn't need the join with `Attendance`, since I have a `Root<Attendance>`, but it worked. Would you like to submit the answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Thanks but the answer is yours, you can post it. I'm glad the link helped.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Following [@GaëlMarziou](https://stackoverflow.com/users/93960/ga%C3%ABl-marziou)'s advice, I've implemented simple methods create the `Specification<Attendance>` for joining with `Student` and `Course`.

I added the fields, getters and setters to `AttendanceCriteria` class, and recompiled to update the JPA metamodel:

```java
private LongFilter studentId;

private LongFilter courseId;

public LongFilter getStudentId() {
    return studentId;
}

public void setStudentId(LongFilter studentId) {
    this.studentId = studentId;
}

public LongFilter getCourseId() {
    return courseId;
}

public void setCourseId(LongFilter courseId) {
    this.courseId = courseId;
}
```

Here's the updated snippet from `AttencanceQueryService` class:

```java
private Specification<Attendance> createSpecification(AttendanceCriteria criteria) {
    Specification<Attendance> specification = Specification.where(null);
    if (criteria != null) {
        if (criteria.getId() != null) {
            specification = specification.and(buildSpecification(criteria.getId(), Attendance_.id));
        }
        if (criteria.getDate() != null) {
            specification = specification.and(buildRangeSpecification(criteria.getDate(), Attendance_.date));
        }
        if (criteria.getEnrollmentId() != null) {
            specification = specification.and(buildReferringEntitySpecification(criteria.getEnrollmentId(), Attendance_.enrollment, Enrollment_.id));
        }
        if (criteria.getStudentId() != null) {
            specification = specification.and(buildJoinSpecification(criteria.getStudentId(), Attendance_.enrollment, Enrollment_.student, Student_.id));
        }
        if (criteria.getCourseId() != null) {
            specification = specification.and(buildJoinSpecification(criteria.getCourseId(), Attendance_.enrollment, Enrollment_.course, Course_.id));
        }
    }
    return specification;
}

private <REFERENCE, JOIN, FILTER extends Comparable<? super FILTER>> Specification<Attendance> buildJoinSpecification(RangeFilter<FILTER> filter, SingularAttribute<? super Attendance, REFERENCE> reference, SingularAttribute<REFERENCE, JOIN> joinField, SingularAttribute<JOIN, FILTER> valueField) {
    Specification<Attendance> result = Specification.where((Specification) null);
    if (filter.getEquals() != null) {
        result = this.equalsSpecification(reference, joinField, valueField, filter.getEquals());
    }
    if (filter.getIn() != null) {
        result = this.valueIn((SingularAttribute) reference, joinField, valueField, filter.getIn());
    }
    return result;
}

private <REFERENCE, JOIN, FILTER> Specification<Attendance> equalsSpecification(SingularAttribute<? super Attendance, REFERENCE> reference, SingularAttribute<REFERENCE, JOIN> joinField, SingularAttribute<JOIN, FILTER> idField, FILTER value) {
    return (root, query, builder) ->
        builder.equal(root.join(reference).join(joinField).get(idField), value);
}

private <REFERENCE, JOIN, FILTER> Specification<Attendance> valueIn(SingularAttribute<? super Attendance, REFERENCE> reference, SingularAttribute<REFERENCE, JOIN> joinField, SingularAttribute<JOIN, FILTER> valueField, Collection<FILTER> values) {
    return (root, query, builder) -> {
        CriteriaBuilder.In<FILTER> in = builder.in(root.join(reference).join(joinField).get(valueField));
        for (FILTER value : values) {
            in = in.value(value);
        }
        return in;
    };
}
```

I hope this helps someone, and the credit goes to [@GaëlMarziou](https://stackoverflow.com/users/93960/ga%C3%ABl-marziou) and [Blackdread/Yoann Caplain](https://github.com/Blackdread).