# Filtering the last element of a chain of JPA entities based on a property in the first

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I tried to shorten this down to the smallest example I could think of on the fly.  In my example I've got store locations by city that are in a state.  A store can have a number of fruits.  A fruit can be in a number of stores.  A fruit can be in a number of states with a cost per state.  And a state can have a number of fruits.

I've got five entities: state, store, store_fruit, fruit, and state_fruit as below:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "STATE")
public class State {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "STATE_ID")
    private Integer stateId;
    @Column(name = "STATE_CD")
    private String stateCd;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "state")
    private Set<StateFruit> stateFruits;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "state")
    private Set<Store> stores;

    public State() {}

    @JsonIgnore
    public Integer getStateId() {
        return stateId;
    }

    public void setStateId(Integer stateId) {
        this.stateId = stateId;
    }

    @JsonView(Views.Info.class)
    @JsonGetter("code")
    public String getStateCd() {
        return stateCd;
    }

    public void setStateCd(String stateCd) {
        this.stateCd = stateCd;
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    public Set<StateFruit> getStateFruits() {
        return stateFruits;
    }

    public void setStateFruits(Set<StateFruit> stateFruits) {
        this.stateFruits = stateFruits;
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    public Set<Store> getStores() {
        return stores;
    }

    public void setStores(Set<Store> stores) {
        this.stores = stores;
    }
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "STORE")
public class Store {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "STORE_ID")
    private Integer storeId;
    @Column(name = "STORE_CITY")
    private String storeCity;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "store")
    private Set<StoreFruit> storeFruits;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "state_id")
    private State state;

    public Store() {}

    @JsonIgnore
    public Integer getStoreId() {
        return storeId;
    }

    public void setStoreId(Integer storeId) {
        this.storeId = storeId;
    }

    @JsonView(Views.Info.class)
    @JsonGetter("city")
    public String getStoreCity() {
        return storeCity;
    }

    public void setStoreCity(String storeCity) {
        this.storeCity = storeCity;
    }

    @JsonView(Views.Info.class)
    @JsonGetter("fruits")
    public Set<StoreFruit> getStoreFruits() {
        return storeFruits;
    }

    public void setStoreFruits(Set<StoreFruit> storeFruits) {
        this.storeFruits = storeFruits;
    }

    @JsonView(Views.Info.class)
    @JsonGetter("state")
    public State getState() {
        return state;
    }

    public void setState(State state) {
        this.state = state;
    }
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "STORE_FRUIT")
public class StoreFruit {

    @EmbeddedId
    private StoreFruitId storeFruitId;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "STORE_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Store store;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "FRUIT_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Fruit fruit;

    public StoreFruit() {}

    @JsonIgnore
    public StoreFruitId getStoreFruitId() {
        return storeFruitId;
    }

    public void setStoreFruitId(StoreFruitId storeFruitId) {
        this.storeFruitId = storeFruitId;
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    public Store getStore() {
        return store;
    }

    public void setStore(Store store) {
        this.store = store;
    }

    @JsonView(Views.Info.class)
    @JsonGetter("fruit")
    public Fruit getFruit() {
        return fruit;
    }

    public void setFruit(Fruit fruit) {
        this.fruit = fruit;
    }
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "FRUIT")
public class Fruit {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "FRUIT_ID")
    private Integer fruitId;
    @Column(name = "FRUIT_NAME")
    private String fruitName;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "fruit")
    private Set<StoreFruit> storeFruits;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "fruit")
    private Set<StateFruit> stateFruits;

    public Fruit() {}

    @JsonIgnore
    public Integer getFruitId() {
        return fruitId;
    }

    public void setFruitId(Integer fruitId) {
        this.fruitId = fruitId;
    }

    @JsonView(Views.Info.class)
    @JsonGetter("name")
    public String getFruitName() {
        return fruitName;
    }

    public void setFruitName(String fruitName) {
        this.fruitName = fruitName;
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    public Set<StoreFruit> getStoreFruits() {
        return storeFruits;
    }

    public void setStoreFruits(Set<StoreFruit> storeFruits) {
        this.storeFruits = storeFruits;
    }

    @JsonView(Views.Info.class)
    @JsonGetter("states")
    public Set<StateFruit> getStateFruits() {
        return stateFruits;
    }

    public void setStateFruits(Set<StateFruit> stateFruits) {
        this.stateFruits = stateFruits;
    }
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "STATE_FRUIT")
public class StateFruit {

    @EmbeddedId
    private StateFruitId stateFruitId;
    @Column(name = "FRUIT_COST")
    private Double fruitCost;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "STATE_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private State state;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "FRUIT_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Fruit fruit;

    public StateFruit() {}

    @JsonIgnore
    public StateFruitId getStateFruitId() {
        return stateFruitId;
    }

    public void setStateFruitId(StateFruitId stateFruitId) {
        this.stateFruitId = stateFruitId;
    }

    @JsonView(Views.Info.class)
    @JsonGetter("cost")
    public Double getFruitCost() {
        return fruitCost;
    }

    public void setFruitCost(Double fruitCost) {
        this.fruitCost = fruitCost;
    }

    @JsonView(Views.Info.class)
    @JsonGetter("state")
    public State getState() {
        return state;
    }

    public void setState(State state) {
        this.state = state;
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    public Fruit getFruit() {
        return fruit;
    }

    public void setFruit(Fruit fruit) {
        this.fruit = fruit;
    }
}
```

Now when I search my store repository for a store id, I get the following JSON output (using a JsonView):

```
{
    "city": "Fort Worth",
    "state": {
        "code": "TX"
    },
    "fruits": [
        {
            "fruit": {
                "name": "Apple",
                "states": [
                    {
                        "cost": 1.75,
                        "state": {
                            "code": "CO"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "cost": 1.5,
                        "state": {
                            "code": "TX"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "fruit": {
                "name": "Banana",
                "states": [
                    {
                        "cost": 2.25,
                        "state": {
                            "code": "CO"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "cost": 2.0,
                        "state": {
                            "code": "TX"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

It all works as I expect it to, **except** I'd like to find some way to filter the states set in the fruit section down to the state for the store I'm looking at.  Because the store circles around the other way through state to state_fruit I thought I could utilize that relationship, I just haven't come across anything like this yet.  Is this possible without having to write a custom query?

Comment: Din you try criteria-specification? it will solve your exact issue. let me know if you need an example

Comment: @SridharPatnaik I'm not familiar with that, so I didn't.  If you have an example that would be great, and then I'll do some searching on my side as well.

Comment: Sorry, I do not have sample code ready. I though I have. Anyways, there are many answers on SO available regarding specification. Specification is a library which can filter data based on any possible condition. example in your case, you can create specification object as per your requirement and then fetch data using that object. Sample - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52424456/how-to-write-a-spring-data-jpa-specification-with-multiple-joins