# Spring / Jhipster QueryService how to build a deep specification

Tags: java, spring, filter, jhipster, criteria

I'm new to QueryService generated with Jhispter, and I'm trying to use them to filter a list of an entity.

It works fine when I filter on fields of this entity, but now I have to do something a bit more complicated.

I have this data set :

- Child <----- the entity I was talking about above
- Parent <----- which has a list of Child
- GrandParent <----- which has a list of Parent

What I have to do is :

- Filter Childs by Parent.name
- Filter Childs by GrandParent.name

So what I've done so far is :

```
private Specification<Child> createSpecification(ChildCriteria criteria) {
    Specification<Child> specification = Specification.where(null);
    if (criteria != null) {
        if (criteria.getParentName() != null) {
            speficiation = specification.and(buildReferringEntitySpecification(criteria.getParentName(), Child_.parent, Parent_.name));
        }
        if (criteria.getGrandParentName() != null) {
            specification.and(buildJoinSpecification(criteria.getGrandParentName(), Child_.parent, Parent_.grandParent, GrandParent_.name));
        }
    }
}
```

An extract of Child, Parent, GrandParent and ChildCriteria :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Child")
public class Child extends EntityObject {
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("childs")
    @QueryInit("GrandParent")
    private Parent parent;
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "Parent")
public class Parent extends EntityObject {
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("parents")
    private GrandParent grandParent;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "Parent", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Child> childs = new HashSet<>();
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "GrandParent")
public class GrandParent extends EntityObject {
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "GrandParent", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Parent> parrents = new HashSet<>();
}



public class ChildCriteria implements Serializable {
    private StringFilter parentName;
    private StringFilter grandParentName;

    public StringFilter getParentName() {
        return parentName;
    }

    public void setParentName(StringFilter parentName) {
        this.parentName= parentName;
    }

    public StringFilter getGrandParentName() {
        return grandParentName;
    }

    public void setGrandParentName(StringFilter grandParentName) {
        this.grandParentName= grandParentName;
    }
}
```

The filter on parent name works, and I'd like to do the same for the grand parent name.
And for that one, I tried several tips I found on SO like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52424456/how-to-write-a-spring-data-jpa-specification-with-multiple-joins), but nothing worked.

From that link, here's what I have so far :

```
public class ExtendedQueryService<ENTITY> extends QueryService<ENTITY>{
    protected <REFERENCE, JOIN, FILTER extends Comparable<? super FILTER>> Specification<ENTITY> buildJoinSpecification(StringFilter filter, SingularAttribute<? super ENTITY, REFERENCE> reference, SingularAttribute<REFERENCE, JOIN> joinField, SingularAttribute<JOIN, FILTER> valueField) {
        Specification<ENTITY> result = Specification.where((Specification) null);
        if (filter.getContains() != null) {
            result = this.containsSpecification(reference, joinField, valueField, filter.getContains());
        }
        return result;
    }

    protected  <REFERENCE, JOIN, FILTER> Specification<ENTITY> containsSpecification(SingularAttribute<? super ENTITY, REFERENCE> reference, SingularAttribute<REFERENCE, JOIN> joinField, SingularAttribute<JOIN, FILTER> idField, String value) {
        return (root, query, builder) ->
            builder.equal(root.join(reference).join(joinField).get(idField), value);
    }
}
```

I extend this class in my ChildQueryService, where I use the buildJoinSpecification method.

And it returns an empty list if I try to filter with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I found something in Jhipster doc. Problem was that I use a StringFilter, when I understood that, I modified few things from Jhipster functions like this :

ExtendedQueryService :

```
protected Specification<ENTITY> buildSpecification(StringFilter filter, Function<Root<ENTITY>, Expression<String>> metaclassFunction) {
        if (filter.getEquals() != null) {
            return equalsSpecification(metaclassFunction, filter.getEquals());
        } else if (filter.getIn() != null) {
            return valueIn(metaclassFunction, filter.getIn());
        } else if (filter.getNotIn() != null) {
            return valueNotIn(metaclassFunction, filter.getNotIn());
        } else if (filter.getContains() != null) {
            return likeUpperSpecification(metaclassFunction, filter.getContains());
        } else if (filter.getDoesNotContain() != null) {
            return doesNotContainSpecification(metaclassFunction, filter.getDoesNotContain());
        } else if (filter.getNotEquals() != null) {
            return notEqualsSpecification(metaclassFunction, filter.getNotEquals());
        } else if (filter.getSpecified() != null) {
            return byFieldSpecified(metaclassFunction, filter.getSpecified());
        }
        return null;
    }
```

So that I could do this in my ChildQueryService :

```
if (criteria.getGrandParentName() != null) {
    specification = specification.and(
        buildSpecification(
            criteria.getGrandParentName(),
            root -> root.join(Child_.parent, JoinType.INNER).join(Parent_.grandParent, JoinType.INNER).get(GrandParent_.name)
        )
    );
}
```

And it works fine now ! It seems you can go as deep as you want with the join, though I didn't test it further than 2 level depth.

For the record, this is what I found in Jhipster doc, and what I based my function on :

```
protected <OTHER, MISC, X> Specification<ENTITY> buildReferringEntitySpecification(
    Filter<X> filter,
    Function<Root<ENTITY>, SetJoin<MISC, OTHER>> functionToEntity,
    Function<SetJoin<MISC, OTHER>, Expression<X>> entityToColumn
) {
    if (filter.getEquals() != null) {
        return equalsSpecification(functionToEntity.andThen(entityToColumn), filter.getEquals());
    } else if (filter.getSpecified() != null) {
        return byFieldSpecified(root -> functionToEntity.apply(root), filter.getSpecified());
    }
    return null;
}
```

which was used that way for instance :

```
buildReferringEntitySpecification(
    criteria.getGrandParentName(),
    root ->  root.get(Child_.parent).join(Parent_.grandParent),
    GrandParent_.name
)
```

Using both allows to handle StringFilter and other Filters. You might have to do specific function for some Filter class though.

Answer (score 1):

The `tech.jhipster.service.QueryService` can get complicate quickly.  I'm looking at my code after 6 months, and I don't get what I did anymore, having to rethink stuff again, just because I want to add a little thing.  Therefore: Don't use it, if you can avoid it.

For complicated filtering I suggest creating a view in the database, that mapped what I wanted to filter to a String, or Boolean, create an Entity in Spring (take care that the ID is non-null and matching the original entity, so just add fields via the view, don't filter stuff out or duplicate entities by accident) and then filtered that.  It's complicated, yes, but less complicated than `QueryService`.

SQL is way easier than using an API that's a layer on top of hibernates `Criteria` API, which itself is also a little bit more complicated than SQL.

In my case wanted to filter depending on multiple attributes at once - there is no easy way to do this in `QueryService`, but `case` ... `when`... outputting an enum, that can then be filtered by `QuerySerivice` is easy enough (and I'll understand what I did in a year).

Comment: That's actually what we ended up doing few years after ! As of today, I'd really go for this instead of the QueryService.